# Checking loop for match most efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I have a simple set up to find top scores. The goal is to order who received the highest scores and then give the top 3 bonus points.

**Question:** In part two below I am looping through the people and checking who got the top score. The issue is I need to do this 3 times for each name. The way I currently have the loop set up works but seems very redundant. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
   var allGrades = [
        {name: 'andrew', score: 80}, 
        {name: 'john', score: 90}, 
        {name: 'sam', score: 31}, 
        {name: 'frank', score: 50}, 
        {name: 'dave', score: 95},
        ]

    allGrades.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
    return obj2.score - obj1.score;
     });
```

Part two. Giving the top 3 scoring people a bonus of 50/25/15 accordingly.

```
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

if (allGrades[0].name == 'andrew'){
andrewGradeBonus = 50; 
if (allGrades[1].name == 'andrew'){
andrewGradeBonus = 25;
if (allGrades[2].name == 'andrew'){
andrewGradeBonus = 15;

if (allGrades[0].name == 'dave'){
daveGradeBonus = 50; 
if (allGrades[1].name == 'dave'){
daveGradeBonus = 25;
if (allGrades[2].name == 'dave'){
daveGradeBonus = 15;
```

continued for all names...

Comment: How do you use the bonus later? i.e the variables like `andrewGradeBonus`. Because after the sorting procedure you will already know what bonus correspond to every one.

Comment: Hm. My issue is I'm not sure how to actually get that data saved to a new variable like (andrewGradeBonus) without going through the second step.

Comment: You can store the bonus inside the objects, for example: `allGrades.sort(...).map(({name, score}, idx) => ({name, score, bonus: getBonus(idx)}))` and where `getBonus()` is a method that returns the corresponding bonus for each position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but if you're already sorting, there is no need to loop again. You already know the three persons with the highest scores which are are at index 0, 1 and 2. I'd just do the following:

```
 var allGrades = [
        {name: 'andrew', score: 80}, 
        {name: 'john', score: 90}, 
        {name: 'sam', score: 31}, 
        {name: 'frank', score: 50}, 
        {name: 'dave', score: 95},
        ]

    allGrades.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
    return obj2.score - obj1.score;
     });


allGrades[0]["bonusPoints"] = 50; 
allGrades[1]["bonusPoints"] = 25; 
allGrades[2]["bonusPoints"] = 15;
```

Therefore, allGrades would look like this:

```
[{name:"dave",score:95,bonusPoints:50},
 {name:"john",score:90,bonusPoints:25}, 
 {name:"andrew",score:80,bonusPoints:15},
 {name:"frank",score:50}, 
 {name:"sam",score:31}]
```

As you can see, in the result above, you know dave have a 95 score with 50 bonus points. andrew 90 with 25 bonus points, and andrew 80 with 15 bonus points. The rest have no bunus points.

Answer (score 3):

You could just iterate over the grades and increase the actual score:

```
const gradeBonuses = [50, 25, 15];
allGrades.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score).forEach((grade, index) => {
    if (index < 3) {
        grade.score += gradeBonuses[index];
    }
});
```

If you *really* want the separate bonus prop, just switch `grade.score += gradeBonuses[index];` with

```
const bonusProp = `${grade.name.toLowerCase()}GradeBonus`
       grade[bonusProp] = gradeBonuses[index];
```

But seeing as the object already has the name stored in it, why do you need to add the name to the name of your bonus property as well?

Comment: Super helpful - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `sort` and `map`. My approach is to check the index within the `sort` callback - since the array is already sorted descending on `score` we can use the callback `idx` argument to appropriately assign the `bonus` points:

```js
const allScores = [{
    name: 'andrew',
    score: 80
  },
  {
    name: 'john',
    score: 90
  },
  {
    name: 'sam',
    score: 31
  },
  {
    name: 'frank',
    score: 50
  },
  {
    name: 'dave',
    score: 95
  }
];

const updateTopScores = allScores => {
  return allScores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score).map((el, idx) => {
    switch (idx) {
      case 0:
        el.bonus = 50
        break;
      case 1:
        el.bonus = 25
        break;
      case 2:
        el.bonus = 15
        break;
      default:
        el.bonus = 0;
    }
    
    return el;
  });
};


console.log(updateTopScores(allScores))
```

Comment: Super helpful - Thank you!

Comment: Np, Glad it helps!